# CFFI - Use struct with #ifdef

Tags: python, python-cffi, cffi

Currently I am wrapping some existing C-Code to Python. It is working quite well with CFFI, but there is one last thing i don't get.

How do I handle "#ifdef" statements?

Let's say i have this struct in c:

```
typedef struct can_config_tag
{
    char_t type[4];
    uint16_t module_nr;
#ifdef CAN_MON
    uint16_t rx_main_mon;
#endif
    byte_t rx_obj;
}
```

I don't understand how i handle wrapping these "#ifdef" statements. In the documentation i found something with "...;" but how can i access the data of the struct then?

When trying to use ... and access the data with:

```
can_config= ffi.new("can_config_tag *")
can_config.rx_main_mon = 2
```

I get an error saying:

```
AttributeError: cdata 'struct can_config_tag*' has no field 'rx_main_mon'
```

So is there any workaround on how to handle these preprocessor directives when using cffi? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ffi.cdef()` cannot give a result that depends on preprocessing directives, because these are only known later, when the C compiler is called.  (This could maybe be fixed in case of out-of-line builds, but it's not immediate.)

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Do several compilation steps.
2. Don't expose the optional field but add custom accessor functions.

For 1., write something like this:

```
ffi_pre = FFI()
ffi_pre.cdef("#define CAN_MON_IS_DEFINED ...")
ffi_pre.set_source("_tmp_cffi", """
    #include <foo_mon.h>
    #ifdef CAN_MON
    #  define CAN_MON_IS_DEFINED 1
    #else
    #  define CAN_MON_IS_DEFINED 0
    #endif
""")
ffi_pre.compile()
from _tmp_cffi import ffi as ffi_tmp
can_mon = ffi_tmp.CAN_MON_IS_DEFINED
```

...then write the rest of the code like you already have, but use `if can_mon:` somewhere as Python code, e.g. build the string in the cdef like that:

```
"""
typedef struct can_config_tag
{
    char_t type[4];
    uint16_t module_nr;
""" + ("uint16_t rx_main_mon;" if can_mon else "") + """
    byte_t rx_obj;
};
"""
```

The solution number 2 is to never define the field `rx_main_mon`, but instead add C functions that read and write it if the field is defined:

```
ffi.cdef("""
typedef struct can_config_tag
{
    char_t type[4];
    uint16_t module_nr;
    byte_t rx_obj;
};
int my_read_rx_main_mon(struct can_config_tag *);
void my_write_rx_main_mon(struct can_config_tag *, int value);
""")
ffi.set_source("somename", """
#include <foomon.h>
static int my_read_rx_main_mon(struct can_config_tag *p)
{
#ifdef CAN_MON
    return p->rx_main_mon;
#else
    return -1;
#endif
}
static void my_write_rx_main_mon(struct can_config_tag *p, int value)
{
#ifdef CAN_MON
    p->rx_main_mon = value;
#endif
}
""")
```